# $\mathbb{A}^1$ contractibility under base change

Tags: algebraic-geometry, homotopy-theory

Call a variety $X$ $\mathbb{A}^1$-contractible if $X\cong\operatorname{Spec}{k}$ in the Morel-Voevodosky $\mathbb{A}^1$-homotopy category.

If $X$ over a field $k$ is $\mathbb{A}^1$ contractible, does this imply $X_{k'}$ is $\mathbb{A}^1$ contractible where $k'$ is a separable field extension over $k$?

Any help or reference will be appreciated.

Comment: Is this contractibility notion just about the existence of a map $h: \mathbb{A}^1 \times X\rightarrow X$ such that $h(0,\cdot)$ is constant and $h(1,\cdot)$ is the identity? If so, you can just base change this map. If not, what’s the definition?

Comment: A scheme $X$ over $k$ is $\mathbb{A}^1$-contractible if $X \cong Spec \ k$ in Morel-Voevodosky $\mathbb{A}^1$-homotopy category.